# Checking vsvars32.bat is run or not

Tags: .net

Can I ensure the batch file `vsvars32.bat` has run or not? Is there any environment variable through which I can confirm that it has been run or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong question.  If you are not sure then make sure by running it again.  It's quick.

But if you really want to you could do something like this:

```
 if "%vsinstalldir%" == "" goto envnotset
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess either of the following would be ok:

```
@SET VSINSTALLDIR=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
@SET VCINSTALLDIR=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC
```